# Windows 8.1: some settings lost after restart

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I'm not sure when it started, perhaps after installing one of the updates, but now I have the following issue on my laptop with Windows 8.1:

Every time I restart my PC, some settings get lost. For example:

- Every time I restart and launch Firefox, it asks me whether I want to set it as the default browser, even though it should already be the default one.
- After a restart, all tray icons are hidden behind [the arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZnP3.png), even if some of them weren't hidden before restarting.

What might be the issue here? It's not a huge deal, as I usually hibernate, but It's a bit annoying, and I want to know what's going on.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but you *are* a local administrator on this computer, right?

Comment: @Catatonic27 Yes, my user is administrator, but not the one with the name _Administrator_. Basically, it's the one created while installing Windows. I didn't create/remove users on the computer afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems. Some personalization themes and the win 8 charms lost after restart. 
What solved this for me is that instead of regualrly using the system from the Administrator user,
I set up an additional user on my name. so I have two users Administrator with all the previlages, and Myname user with the previlages I want it to have.
That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, but I hoped to avoid measures such as creating a new user or reinstalling Windows. Let's see if there are other answers.

Comment: I finally got around to creating a new account. It helped indeed, thanks.